# gtk helloworld compile error on ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gtk

I installed gtk on ubuntu with command
sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev

then I copied code into vi editor

I copied the following code for helloworld in GTK which gives compile error

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

/* this is a callback function. the data arguments are ignored in this example..
 * More on callbacks below. */
void hello (GtkWidget *widget, gpointer *data)
{
    g_print ("Hello World\n");
}

/* another callback */
void destroy (GtkWidget *widget, gpointer *data)
{
    gtk_main_quit ();
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /* GtkWidget is the storage type for widgets */
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *button;

    /* this is called in all GTK applications.  arguments are parsed from
     * the command line and are returned to the application. */
    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    /* create a new window */
    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

    /* when the window is given the "destroy" signal (this can be given
    * by the application, or the window manager, the function destroy
    * will be called as defined above.  The data passed to the callback
    * function is NULL and is ignored in the callback. */
    gtk_signal_connect (GTK_OBJECT (window), "destroy",
                        GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC (destroy), NULL);

    /* sets the border width of the window. */
    gtk_container_border_width (GTK_CONTAINER (window), 10);

    /* creates a new button with the label "Hello World". */
    button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Hello World");

    /* When the button receives the "clicked" signal, it will call the
     * function hello() passing it NULL as it's argument.  The hello() function is
     * defined above. */
    gtk_signal_connect (GTK_OBJECT (button), "clicked",
                        GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC (hello), NULL);

    /* This will cause the window to be destroyed by calling
     * gtk_widget_destroy(window) when "clicked.  Again, the destroy
     * signal could come from here, or the window manager. */
    gtk_signal_connect_object (GTK_OBJECT (button), "clicked",
                               GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC (gtk_widget_destroy),
                               GTK_OBJECT (window));

    /* this packs the button into the window (a gtk container). */
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), button);

    /* the final step is to display this newly created widget... */
    gtk_widget_show (button);

    /* and the window */
    gtk_widget_show (window);

    /* all GTK applications must have a gtk_main().     Control ends here
     * and waits for an event to occur (like a key press or mouse event). */
    gtk_main ();

    return 0;
}
```

then I compiled with

```
gcc -Wall -g HelloWorld.c -o hello_world -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lglib -lgdk -lgtk -lX11 -lXext -lm
```

it gives compile error

1. HelloWorld.c:4:25: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
    #include

where locate gtk.h gives
/home/user/linux-3.13.0/tools/perf/ui/gtk/gtk.h

I would like to use gtk for trvelling from one GPS co-ordinate to another using shortest path. Is it possible? what about gtkmap API? Where can I find more details and examples?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but your code seems kind of old. I dare to say it's probably using some version circa Gtk+ 1.2.

Anyway, I would advise you to read a Gtk tutorial from GNOME's website, [Getting Started with Gtk+](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-getting-started.html). It targets Gtk+3 which currently is at version 3.26 (stable).

To compile a simple Gtk+ C application you will use [pkg-config](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pkg-config/) to translate the correct paths to the indicate libs.

Let's take a very simple example from the previously indicated guide and save it as **`main.c`**:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void
print_hello (GtkWidget *widget,
             gpointer   data)
{
  g_print ("Hello World\n");
}

static void
activate (GtkApplication *app,
          gpointer        user_data)
{
  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *grid;
  GtkWidget *button;

  /* create a new window, and set its title */
  window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
  gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Window");
  gtk_container_set_border_width (GTK_CONTAINER (window), 10);

  /* Here we construct the container that is going pack our buttons */
  grid = gtk_grid_new ();

  /* Pack the container in the window */
  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), grid);

  button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Button 1");
  g_signal_connect (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (print_hello), NULL);

  /* Place the first button in the grid cell (0, 0), and make it fill
   * just 1 cell horizontally and vertically (ie no spanning)
   */
  gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID (grid), button, 0, 0, 1, 1);

  button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Button 2");
  g_signal_connect (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (print_hello), NULL);

  /* Place the second button in the grid cell (1, 0), and make it fill
   * just 1 cell horizontally and vertically (ie no spanning)
   */
  gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID (grid), button, 1, 0, 1, 1);

  button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Quit");
  g_signal_connect_swapped (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (gtk_widget_destroy), window);

  /* Place the Quit button in the grid cell (0, 1), and make it
   * span 2 columns.
   */
  gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID (grid), button, 0, 1, 2, 1);

  /* Now that we are done packing our widgets, we show them all
   * in one go, by calling gtk_widget_show_all() on the window.
   * This call recursively calls gtk_widget_show() on all widgets
   * that are contained in the window, directly or indirectly.
   */
  gtk_widget_show_all (window);

}

int
main (int    argc,
      char **argv)
{
  GtkApplication *app;
  int status;

  app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
  g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
  status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
  g_object_unref (app);

  return status;
}
```

Then compile it with:

```
gcc -o main main.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

Regarding the maps question, well I would suggest [libchamplain](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/libchamplain), there are some examples on the [github project page](https://github.com/GNOME/libchamplain) in the demos folder.

Don't forget to check [GNOME's Map](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Maps) application and their [github page](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-maps).